# Admin URL to my plugin's page

Tags: wordpress

My plugin is basically a link display page, for instance if you want to display a page with links to other websites.

In wp-admin I have a menu item on the left side bar added with this code:

```
function bls_add_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page('Custom Links', 'Custom Links', 'manage_options', 
                  'customlinks', 'bsl_admin_page', '', 15);
}
```

After adding a new link, I want to redirect to my plugin home page in admin. The URL when I click on my plugin menu link is :

```
localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=customlinks
```

How do I get that URL in Worpdress? Currently I just do this :

```
wp_redirect('/wp-admin/admin.php?page=customlinks');
```

but I hope there is a better way of getting my plugin admin URL?

Comment: use menu_page_url( 'customlinks', true ) to echo out the link wherever you need. Note the true parameter tells to echo the link so no need to use echo.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You get the concrete URL to `admin.php` by using the [`admin_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) function:

```
admin_url('admin.php'); # http(s)://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php
```

That function chooses the proper sheme (http/https) based on your Wordpress configuration for you so you do not need to care about it. Same for the path to the admin. The only thing you need to specify is the file name (`admin.php`).

And in your concrete example you add the *page* query-info part:

```
$url = admin_url('admin.php?page=customlinks');
wp_redirect($url);
```

Answer (score 11):

URL for menu page or options page has 'page' parameter ( page slug defined in add_menu_page() or add_options_page() ). You can always get the current page from $_GET['page'] param, so URL for the options page is:

```
admin_url( "options-general.php?page=".$_GET["page"] )
```

, and URL for menu page ( actually it works with options pages also ) is:

```
admin_url( "admin.php?page=".$_GET["page"] )
```